# BIRT Detail report with 1 million Records

Tags: birt, rows

I am using open source BIRT reports. I developed a detail reports. The setting are per page 100 records. There are more then 1 million records. When I show the reports it failed to show that report and stuck in processing 1 million records. Is the some server side pagination in BIRT like Crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

Commercial BIRT has some controls which help in this regard.  With the Open Source version you are likely just running out of memory on the JVM.  What output format are you trying to send the report to?  HTML?  PDF?